# How do I maintain stack in NASM using in Ubuntu11.04

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, stack, nasm

For my project work, I have tested a code snippet. And I found that this code snippet arises **segmentation fault** due to the use of stack.Yet, I have to solve it **using stack.** Can any one help me to find out the problem? My program will display the second character of the string variable. My code snippet is following:

```
section.data
  string db "test",10,0
  msg2   db "%c",10,0
main:

xor eax,eax
mov eax, string
mov ebx,1    ; suppose I want to get the second character of string. SO I store the index of that character in ebx

pusha
push eax
push ebx
add esp,8
popa

pop dword[ebx]   ;  **I assume that this following 3 lines arise segmentation fault**   
pop eax          ;
mov bl,[eax+ebx] ; I want to move the fisrt character to BL using the index value stored in ebx which i popped just.

pusha
push ebx
call putchar
add esp,4
popa

pusha
push msg2
call printf
add esp,4
popa
```

Here, for your kind consideration I want to make it clear that the purpose of this code snippet is to know **how to manipulate a stack.**

Here, @nrz  has recently given me a idea of the following code and I edit my above code here:

```
  section.data
    string db "test",10,0
    msg2   db "%c",10,0
  main:
    xor eax,eax
    mov eax, string
    mov ebx,1  ; suppose I want to get the second character of string. SO I store the index of that character in ebx
    mov   eax,string
    movzx eax,byte [eax]
    push  eax        ; these push and pop are for solving it using the stack,
    pop   ebx
    pusha
    push ebx
    call putchar
    add esp,4
    popa
    pusha
    push msg2
    call printf
    add esp,4
    popa
```

My query is specifcally:

1. I will give the index value. Should it be in the `ebx` register?
2. And above all my main idea of using stack is to acccess every character of `string` variable using the index value I pushed in `ebx` earlier. [It is mandatory. is it possible?]
3. I want to store the output in a 8-bit register also.

   So my all in all idea is something like:

   ```
   mov al, [string+ebx]   ;is it possible?
   ```

   I have to take the value of `ebx` from the stack. I will put a value in `ebx`, then `push ebx` and at the time of `mov al,[string+ebx]`, I will `pop ebx` to get the value for `mov` instruction. More likely the instructions will be looked like:

   ```
    pop ebx  
    mov al,[string+dword[ebx]]  ;which is a wrong statement shown by NASM
   ```

I am eagerly waiting for your response.

THank you,

Comment: The value pushed with `push ebx` right before `call putchar` is the ASCII code, not any kind of index nor memory address. Generally it is not possible to "access every character of string" using that value. Roughly there are two options how to print: 1. looping through the string, and printing it character at the time (eg. with `call putchar`, as in your code), or 2. print it the complete string at once, using `call printf` or Linux API `write` function (`4`). But if the string length is predetermined to be exactly 4 bytes, like `test`, it is possible. Is the string length always 4 bytes?

Comment: `mov al, [string+ebx]` is certainly a possible instruction, but **it does not use the stack**, if that was the requirement. See my edited answer for both 'normal' `mov al, [string+ebx]` code and 'using stack' code: `push dword [ebx+string]`, `and  dword [esp], 0x000000ff`, `pop  eax`.

Comment: @nrz: i dont know, how can I express my gratitude to you and express my regret that may be my less knowledge of English is not helping you to get my idea. I express my apology  for this. I mentioned that I have to take the value of ebx from stack. I will put a value in ebx, then PUSH THE EBX and at the time of mov al,[string+ebx], I will pop ebx to get the value for mov instruction. More likely,it will be mov al,[string+dword[ebx]](which is a wrong statement showing by NASM).But in your code, theres no way to pop the value of ebx to execute "string"

Comment: `mov al,[string+dword[ebx]]` does not make sense at all, at the least it's not NASM syntax and then, independently of the specific x86 assembler in use, `al` is a `byte`, not `dword`, and the size operand must be written outside square brackets (it would be `byte`, but it's **not** needed, as `al` is always `byte`), not inside, as you have, and there is no addressing form in x86 assembly that would use double square brackets like in your code `[string+dword[ebx]]`. If you have a valid index on the top of the stack, all you need is `pop ebx`, `mov al,[ebx+string]`.

Comment: `mov eax,string`, `mov ebx,1` does not give the 2nd character of the string, but after these 2 instructions eg. `mov cl,[eax+ebx]` will store it in `cl`. To get the second character of the string, all you need is `mov al,[string+1]`. In the original code already the `pop dword[ebx]` may cause a segmentation fault, if you don't have **write access** to `[ebx]`. `pop eax` can not cause segmentation fault in normal conditions, it's a normal `pop` from the stack into a general register `eax`. Then, `mov bl,[ebx+eax]` may cause segmentation fault, if you don't have **read access** to `[ebx+eax]`.

Comment: If you don't handle stack in any way except with `push` and `pop` instructions, `push eax`, `push ebx`, `add esp,8` is absolutely unnecessary. All it does is that it pushes first `eax`, then `ebx`, and then restores `esp` back to it's original value. So it's the same as `push eax`, `push ebx`, `pop ebx`, `pop eax`; in the end all registers involved (`eax`, `ebx`, `esp`) have their original values.

Comment: it means that                                                                       `mov eax, string
       mov ebx,1
       push eax
       push ebx
       add esp,8 
       pop ebx     
       pop eax                                                                        mov bl,[eax+ebx]`                                         this code segment has no way to execute.Because the segmentaion fault arises at the last mov.

Comment: Yes, that's because your stack is not in balance: `push eax`, `push ebx`, `add esp,8`, `pop ebx`, `pop eax`. Each `push` subtracts `esp` by 4, and each `pop` adds 4 to `esp`, and then with `add esp,8` you add 8 more to `esp`, causing imbalance of the stack. Also, the entire `push eax`, `push ebx`, `add esp,8`, `pop ebx`, `pop eax` block is completely unnecessary. You should leave it off, as it serves no purpose (except as a very basic code obfuscation). If you want to play with `push` and `pop` instructions, anyway keep your stack in balance, otherwise segmentation fault is more than probable.

Answer (score 0):

There are some bugs and unnecessary instructions in the code:

```
mov eax, string  ; this line makes eax point to string, but...
xor eax,eax      ; this line zeroes eax immediately. delete this line.
mov ebx,1        ; this line is unnecessary, but does not cause problems.

pusha            ; unnecessary.
push eax         ; unnecessary.
push ebx         ; unnecessary.
add esp,8        ; unnecessary.
popa             ; unnecessary.

pop dword[ebx]   ; [1] = [esp], esp = esp+4, probably causes segmentation fault.
pop eax          ; eax = [esp], esp = esp+4
mov bl,[eax+ebx]
```

**Edit:** to print all the characters, just loop through the string:

```
section.data
  string db "test",10
  string_length equ $-string ; number of characters in the string.
                             ; no zero needed in the end of the string.
  msg2   db "%c",10,0
main:
    xor eax,eax      ; eax is the index to the string.

char_loop:
    push dword [eax+string]      ; push 4 first characters into stack.
    and  dword [esp], 0x000000ff ; x86 is little-endian, so 1st character
                                 ; is the lowest byte.
    pop  ebx                     ; pop the ASCII code of the character into ebx.

    pushad
    push ebx
    call putchar
    add esp,4
    popad

    inc eax
    cmp eax,string_length
    jb  char_loop
```

**Edit:** New code to match the changes in the question, using `ebx` as an index.

```
section.data
  string db "test",10
  string_length equ $-string ; number of characters in the string.
                             ; no zero needed in the end of the string.
  msg2   db "%c",10,0
main:
    xor  eax,eax             ; zero eax, for putchar.
    xor  ebx,ebx             ; ebx is the index to the string.

char_loop:
    ;push dword [ebx+string]      ; push 4 first characters into stack.
    ;and  dword [esp], 0x000000ff ; x86 is little-endian, so 1st character
    ;                             ; is the lowest byte.
    ;pop  eax                     ; pop the ASCII code of the character into ebx.

    mov   al,[ebx+string]         ; this is the normal way to do it.
                                  ; the above 3 instructions do it "using stack",
                                  ; as requested in the question.
    pushad
    push eax
    call putchar
    add esp,4
    popad

    inc ebx
    cmp ebx,string_length
    jb  char_loop
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. But i am afraid that it will solve my purpose. My target is to access the each character from string variable using the index value stored in ebx. Above at the question section I reedit my question using your code showing what output I got. My another query is, you are popping ebx but when did you push it?

Comment: It's pushed right above: `push eax`. I'm not sure if I have understood correctly your question. Could you please edit your question to make it clear what you want to accomplish with your code (there's both `call putchar` and `call printf`, refence to nonexistent `msg2` etc.) and what are the limitations you impose on possible solutions ("using stack" is not specific enough).

Comment: you are so kind,my mentor.But my queries will may create disturbance to you. Yet I hope that you will answer. I asked that I will access every character of "string" variable by using the SUPPLIED index value which I have stored in ebx and I want to store the value in 8 bit register defintiely. I am now going to be doubtful that My idea will work.

Comment: Note that after the instructions `movzx eax,byte [eax]`, `push eax`, `pop ebx` `ebx` (`bl`, specifically) does hold the **ASCII code** of the current character, not an index to the string. It's just an ASCII code (well, it can be used as an index to the **font data** somewhere, but it's not an index to the **string** and can't be used as such).